# Taking out few words from a sentence within characters using UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

Suppose I am extracting Column-6 from the given line. Can you please tell me how to extract the words in between ''?

```
ABC 123 HIJ 788sd78 XYZ I don't need this '**I just want this**'. (Separated by tabs.)
grep ABC filename | awk -F"tab" '{print $6}' | __
```

Please help me out.

Comment: how many `'...'`s in your line? only exists in $6? or could be in other columns? also the `'` in **don't** also a part of your line?

Comment: @user3251769 was any of the answers helpful to you? If so, don't hesitate and mark them as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep -Po` for this:

```
$ grep -Po "(?<=')[^']*" <<< "ABC 123 HIJ 788sd78 XYZ I dont need this 'I just want this'"
I just want this
```

And you can even compact the `grep ABC filename | awk -F"tab" '{print $6}'` into something like:

```
awk -F"\t" '/ABC/{print $6}' file | grep -Po "(?<=')[^']*"
```

#### Example

```
$ cat a
a       b       c       d       e       ABC 123 HIJ 788sd78 XYZ I dont need this 'I just want this'
a       b       c       d       e       aaa 123 HIJ 788sd78 XYZ I dont need this 'I just want this'
$ awk -F"\t" '/ABC/{print $6}' a | grep -Po "(?<=')[^']*"
I just want this
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have single quotes within the text you do not want, as shown in your posted sample input (in `don't`):

```
$ cat file
ABC     123     HIJ     788sd78 XYZ     I don't need this '**I just want this**'.

$ awk -F'\t' '/ABC/{ sub(/\047[^\047]*$/,""); sub(/.*\047/,"") }1' file
**I just want this**
```

Note the need to use `\047` or similar to represent a `'` for command line awk script invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way to get the sixth field from tab-separated standard input:

cut -f 6

e.g.

```
grep ABC filename | cut -f 6
```

Assuming we do not have any quotes before or in the quoted field in the sixth field, and that the quoted field is always there:

```
grep ABC filename | cut -f 6 | cut -f2 -d\'
```

Comment: True but that's not what the poster is asking for.

Comment: Well, if he just wants something in single quotes in the sixth field, grep ABC filename | cut -f 6 | cut -f2 -d\' (the original poster was not 100% clear on what he wanted)

Comment: that would print `t need this ` given his posted sample input.

Comment: I presumed that his real world input doesn't have ' in the data before the data he wants to extract.  If it does, then awk -F\' '{print $(NF - 1)}'  But you know that.